# How can I get my session data to store correctly?

Tags: php, forms, session, http-redirect

I've looked at a variety of threads here already, to no avail, so here's a 'not really' duplicate question since nobody seems to have provided an answer that helps.

I'm working on a webpage that will need to store and pass session data to other various web pages.  Pretty basic... supposedly.

After I navigate to another page (that has the session stored) through my nav, the session data simply disappears, even though the session is still represented.

I've got

`<?php session_start(); ?>`

right at the top of all of my pages.  Check that off my list.

In the header I've got:  `<?php echo 'EMAIL: ' . $_SESSION['email']; ?>` This is just so I can see the physical results of the session... especially when it stops working.

In this specific case, I'm starting the basic structure of a login. An example of how I've got the setup in my code is:

`<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@university.edu">
<label for="email"> Email</label> <br>
<?php $_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email']; ?>`

All my information fills the array just fine when I submit the form, but once again (as mentioned previously), if I navigate (even to the same page) with my user nav, the session data clears.

*Some other helpful debugging information for those willing to take a stab at this:* PHP.ini is set to keep cookies until the browser session is closed, and cookies are an exemption on my browser for my local site.  I'm not sure why it just dumps the session data... It's like it starts a new session entirely.

**I'm aware this is bare-bones, as there isn't any hashing going on... Just the basics to start until I get this working.

Thank you in advance.  I'll do my best to be on top of this thread to answer questions as they come up about my 0200 - written code...

Comment: try `$_SESSION`, you seem to have forgotten a underscore _ in `<?php $SESSION['email'] `

Comment: I don't see any form

Comment: So you changed `$SESSION` to `$_SESSION` and it still does not work? Have a look at your "Network tab" in Developer Tools and first verify you get the same session ID after moving to another page. Verify the appropriate cookie is properly set, use the "Application tab" to verify that. After that, check your error log and look for any errors (like: can't create session file: Filesystem permission denied). Also check the session settings in the php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

> if I navigate (even to the same page) with my user nav, the session data clears.

Since your page includes `$SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email'];`, you will overwrite it with the new value of `$_GET['email']`, which is undefined.